# checking existance of the list element via c# functions

Tags: c#

I have a list like:

```
 List<int> baslikIndexes = new List<int> { };
```

and I added the elements manually. I want to know whether for example if element "23" is in it or not. I am trying to use "Exists" method but I haven't figured out how to use it. I tried this and it gives error:

```
  baslikIndexes.Exists(Predicate<int>(23)); // I try to check whether 23 is in the list or not
```

Thanks for help..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<int> lstint = new List<int>() { 5, 15, 23, 256, 55 };
bool ysno = lstint.Exists(p => p == 23);
```

Answer (score 6):

use `baslikIndexes.Contains(23);`

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `baslikIndexes.Contains(23)` here, but if you'd like to use the `Exists()` method you can use it like this:

```
baslikIndexes.Exists(x => x == 23);
```

Read more about [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) on MSDN.